# How to call pl/sql procedures and functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

I have to call a procedure and functions in java script. Please let me know how do i do it ?

Comment: I don't think you can access database directly via JS, because a database is normally meant to be on the server. You might want to have a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987437/how-to-access-database-through-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You will need a server side language for this. Use AJAX and make a call to a serverside page which can call the procedure and return the response back.