# how do i submit a form which will run my cursor in plsql ?

Tags: javascript, html, plsql, toad

i have a cursor in my procedure which i want to run when a user types in student id in the form field and clicks the button submit. so how do i exactly go on about doing that? so far i have nothing and im pretty new at plsql.

-- cursor is called C_Students 
-- my form button and search box below.

```
htp.p ('<input type="text" name="student_id" placeholder="e.g. 000123456"');
htp.br;
htp.p (' <input type="button" onclick="" value="Submit"');
```

Comment: You'll need some kind of framework to manage database interaction (for example [Oracle Apex](https://apex.oracle.com/en/)). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987437/how-to-access-database-through-javascript

Comment: @WilliamRobertson but i'm using Toad for oracle and hard coding everything

Comment: Ah, apologies, just noticed you are using the old `htp.p` etc. I'd forgotten those existed.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson any ideas on how to get about doing it  ?

Comment: No idea, sorry.